# How can I parameterise my search tests using testng and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I am facing an issue on parametrising a search function, in fact i need to feed my test with different keywords :

Here is my class :

```
package Distributed;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TSKZ63700J {

WebDriver driver ;
String BaseURL , winURL , TestURL, androidURL ;
  String ApiURL = "http://frstmwarwebsrv.orsyptst.com:9000/duobject?     searchString=TSK(Z63700J)(000)(Z63700JU10)(000)&filtercheck=nameSWF&p.index=0&p.size=8";
jsonobject json;

String res;

/**
 * Initiate connection
 */
@BeforeTest


public void setup () throws MalformedURLException  

{
    TestURL = "http://frstmwarwebsrv.orsyptst.com:9000";
    BaseURL = "http://10.2.128.126";
    winURL = "http://10.2.128.120:5556/wd/hub";
    androidURL ="http://10.2.128.120:5555/wd/hub";

    DesiredCapabilities wincap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    wincap.setBrowserName("firefox");
    wincap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver ( new URL ( winURL ),  wincap) ;



}

@Test
  public void compareresults () throws IOException, JSONException {
            srch ("TSK(Z63700J)(000)(Z63700JU10)(000)");
            //assertEquals(jsonobject.getresults(ApiURL), "TSK(ZRM760J)(000)(ZRM760JU00)(000)");
            assertEquals(jsonobject.getresults(ApiURL), res);

  }

private void srch(String keyword)  {

    driver.get(TestURL);
      WebElement input1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[1]"));
      input1.sendKeys("guest");
      WebElement input2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[2]"));
      input2.sendKeys("guest");
      WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/button"));
      btn.click();
      WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/nav/div[1]/form/div/input"));
      w1.sendKeys( "TSK(Z63700J)(000)(Z63700JU10)(000)");
      WebElement w2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]"));
      w2.click();
      WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,10 );
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("TSK(Z63700J)(000)(Z63700JU10)(000)")));
      WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.linkText("TSK(Z63700J)(000)(Z63700JU10)(000)"));
     // res = (result.toString()).substring(80,100);
      res =result.getText();



}

private void quitTest() {
    driver.quit();
}

  @AfterTest
public void aftertest ()

{
    quitTest();
}

  }
```

What I would like to do is :

First parametrize the search function, I guess I have to do it at the SendKeys level inside the search function but I am not sure how to do it using Testng.

Secondly I would like alsi to parametrise the APIURL.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

I have done the following :

```
@Parameters({"keyword" , })
@Test
private void srch(String keyword )  {

    driver.get(TestURL);
      WebElement input1 =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[1]"));
      input1.sendKeys("guest");
      WebElement input2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[2]"));
      input2.sendKeys("guest");
      WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/button"));
      btn.click();
      WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/nav/div[1]/form/div/input"));
      w1.sendKeys(keyword);
      WebElement w2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]"));
      w2.click();



}
```

Then changed testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

```
<test name="Search">
    <parameter name="keyword" value="tsk" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="40" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="30" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="A" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(SAW" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(TTA010ON3" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(ARS090J)(000)(ARS090JN30)(000)" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(Z63700J)(000)(Z63700JU10)(000)" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="BAQ703J" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="BAQ703" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="CPE800J" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="NOT700J" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="ZWE010JU" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="ANF010JU0" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TTA010ON3" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="BEN700JU40" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="NOT700JNA5" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="31" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="LBEN00733_GLOBAL" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="LBEN00733" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(ZTA010OU05)(000)" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="CRM :" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(CRM025JU50)(000)" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(ARS090J)(000)(ARS090JN30)(000)" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="TSK(Z63700J)(000)(Z63700JU10)(000)" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="AFF720J" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="SSCC depuis Gold" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="CPE170JR10" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="Uproc Dist: Detection R:\\sysapp\\data\\CPE\\CPE\\wrk\\SSCC_FPLP" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="Trailer: contournement sur le pb de la TVA" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="AA" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="49" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="Internal Activities" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="().-_ @[]" />
    <parameter name="keyword" value="Integration ZCRMI120 01" />

    <classes>
        <class name="Distributed.Search" />
    </classes>
</test>







</suite>
```

however when I run only the last parameter is taken into consideration : Integration ZCRMI120 01

Thanks
Zied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why only the last value is coming is all your parameters have the name as keyword.  so the last parameter value is the last which is updated for the parameter "keyword".  If you would like to use all your parameters, you need to define them differently.  In your case, if you are trying to run the same test with different data, you should use the dataprovider. 
 Your apiurl is a good candidate for a parameter in the testng.xml coz, that is something that would be constant across multiple tests.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG parameters are controlled by the annotation that you can attach to the methods.

**Test.java**

```
@Parameters({"test", "test1"})
public void myTest(String test, String test1) {
  driver.findElement(By.id("txtSearch")).sendKeys(test);
}
```

**Suite.xml**

```
<test name="My Test">
  <classes>
    <parameter name="test" value="searchTerm" />
    <parameter name="test1" value="some other value" />
    <class name="com.my.package.Test" />
  </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clean, you could use a @DataProvider in a separate class from your test to then pass as parameters.

**MyParameters.java**

```
@DataProvider(name = "keywords")
    public static Object[][] ngKeywords() {
    return new Object[][] { { "tsk" }, { "40" }, { "30" }, { "etc" } };
}
```

Then use the DataProvider in your test:

```
@Test(dataProviderClass = MyParameters.class, dataProvider = "keywords")
private void srch(String keyword) {
    someTestStuff();
}
```

This allows you to keep your data and your test separate.

Comment: Thanks Navi, I have managed to make it working with Testng, I just had to add thread count and tests tags in testng.xml. But Thanks for data provider option.